# How do I send an ajax post request to a specific module in Drupal6?

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal, drupal-6

I want to send an ajax post request to a module named sampleTest in  Drupal6.
I have tried some bits of codes but I do not know how to put the module url in the jquery ajax function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'http://localhost/drupal/www/admin/build/modules/module/get/contact', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: "test",
            success:function(data) {
                alert("123");
            },
            complete: function(data){
                alert("complete");  
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this question should be moved to drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

You can't send an AJAX request to a module as such, rather you implement a path in your module (using [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)), provide a page callback for that path that outputs the AJAX response, and then call that path in your AJAX call. This is a very basic example:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['ajax-test'] = array(
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
}

function mymodule_ajax_callback() {
  $post_data = $_POST;

  // Do something with the post data

  $output = array('status' => 'OK');

  // For Drupal 6
  drupal_json($output);
  exit();

  // Or for Drupal 7, just in case you want to know
  drupal_json_output($output);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Then your JS would look like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#one").click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: '/drupal/ajax-test', 
      dataType: 'json', 
      data: "test",
      success:function(data) { 
        alert(data.status); 
      },
      complete: function(data){
        alert("complete")  
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This answer is definitely worth to mark as correct answer! Thx!